# How to consecutively count everything greater than or equal to itself in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say if I have a table that contains Equipment IDs of equipments for each Equipment Type and Equipment Age, how can I do a `Count Distinct` of Equipment IDs that have at least that Equipment Age.

For example, let's say this is all the data we have:

| equipment_type | equipment_id | equipment_age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Screwdriver | A123 | 1 |
| Screwdriver | A234 | 2 |
| Screwdriver | A345 | 2 |
| Screwdriver | A456 | 2 |
| Screwdriver | A567 | 3 |

I would like the output to be:

| equipment_type | equipment_age | count_of_equipment_at_least_this_age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Screwdriver | 1 | 5 |
| Screwdriver | 2 | 4 |
| Screwdriver | 3 | 1 |

Reason is there are 5 screwdrivers that are at least 1 day old, 4 screwdrivers at least 2 days old and only 1 screwdriver at least 3 days old.

So far I was only able to do count of equipments that falls within each equipment_age (like this query shown below), but not "at least that equipment_age".

```
SELECT
equipment_type,
equipment_age,
COUNT(DISTINCT equipment_id) as count_of_equipments
FROM equipment_table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below join-less solution

```
select distinct
  equipment_type,
  equipment_age,
  count(*) over equipment_at_least_this_age as count_of_equipment_at_least_this_age
from equipment_table 
window equipment_at_least_this_age as (
  partition by equipment_type 
  order by equipment_age 
  range between current row and unbounded following
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: if I have multiple equipment_type, is it possible to adjust the query to do the count correctly for each equipment_type?

Comment: sure. above answer should work for multiple types. have you tried? I just double checked - and it does work for multiple types!

Answer (score 0):

Use a self join approach:

```
SELECT
    e1.equipment_type,
    e1.equipment_age,
    COUNT(*) AS count_of_equipments
FROM equipment_table e1
INNER JOIN equipment_table e2
    ON e2.equipment_type = e1.equipment_type AND
       e2.equipment_age >= e1.equipment_age
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tim, the self join logic makes sense. Do you know if there's a more efficient way to achieve the same result? I tried the self join approach but it's taking forever to run.

Comment: So the result came back, but the count_of_equipments appeared to be way larger than the correct values. I wonder if I did something wrong in my syntax - I will double check.

Comment: Does your table have more than one equipment type, and, if so, do you want to report each type-age combination?  Or do you only want one record for each age?

Comment: Yes. My table has 2 equipment types. I would like to report each type-age combination. Maybe I can try COUNT(DISTINCT e2.equipment_id) instead of COUNT(*).

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary or make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY restricts the scope of COUNT to the rows in the group, i.e. it will not let you reach other rows (rows with equipment_age greater than that of the current group). So you need a subquery or windowing functions to get those. One way:

```
SELECT
   equipment_type,
   equipment_age,
   (Select COUNT(*) 
    from equipment_table cnt 
     where cnt.equipment_type = a.equipment_type
       AND cnt.equipment_age >= a.equipment_age
     )  as count_of_equipments
FROM equipment_table a
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

I am not sure if your environment supports this syntax, though. If not, let us know we will find another way.